# Implement Scala read code having Pyspark file as Source

Tags: scala, pyspark

I need to built a module in scala in which source data is coming from two modules present in Pyspark. Can you help me to read data from pyspark to scala module.

Comment: Pyspark is not a file format... Are you trying to execute pyspark code from a Scala function?

Comment: Yes. I want to execute the Pyspark code from Scala function. So that I read the data getting from pyspark code and use it in scala function.

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. I know you can import JVM functions from Pyspark, but not the other way around